# iOS UIScrollView scrolls only horizontally

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I have added `UIScrollView` to a `UIViewController` using Interface Builder. Inside a `UIScrollView` there's a `UILabel` that holds a lot of text. I have added constraints in both `UIScrollView` and a `UILabel`. Problem is when text is too long it only scrolls horizontally but vertically it is truncated. How can I get the UIScrollView's content to scroll vertically. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Textview instead of `uilabel` to insert longer text. Uncheck the editable property. And it will scroll itself, the `uitextview`.

Comment: Thanks @NSNoob it worked after changing text container from UILabel to UITextView

Answer (score 0):

Right now the height of `contentSize` of your `UIScrollView` is equal to the height of `CGFrame` of your `UIScrollView`. If you increase the height, it will scroll vertically as well.

Comment: That it will but why should he use uilabels to insert huge text? He should use uitextview and let the scrollview scroll only vertical.

Comment: @NSNoob Well, I don't really question his judgement. There could be all sorts of reasons and op does need to learn how to adjust the scrolling, which op is having trouble with as well. :D

Comment: @NSNoob your question is perfectly alright as well.